# Unable to get the response from ajax call in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, gridview, yii2

I have a `GirdView` which includes `checkbox`. Now I have a button which i routed to another `action controller`. Below is my code

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          /*'filterModel' => $searchModel,*/
          'id'=>'grid',
       'columns' => [

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        'Meter Serial Number',
        'Issued To',
        'Store',


 ],
]); ?> 
<a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['ogpheader/viewsetpdf','id'=>'myid'])?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="issue_pdf" id="myid" onclick="getRows()">Set PDF</a>


$(document).ready(function () {      

 $('#myid').click(function() {

     var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');

    // alert(keys);

     $.post({     
      url: 'ogpheader/viewsetpdf',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:{keylist: keys},
      success:function(data) {
        alert('Done')
      }

 });
}) });
```

Then in my controller

```
public function actionViewsetpdf()
{
    /*$model = $this->findModel($id);
    print_r($model);*/

    if(isset($_POST['keylist']))
    {
        $keys = json_decode($_POST['keylist']);
        print_r($keys);
    }



    exit();

}
```

When I click on the button i get empty view. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53777-gridview-get-selected-colum/)I don't know what is the problem. I am stuck to it.

**Update1**

While checking it in network

[image: Network Image]

**Update 2**

As suggested I have tried with `$.ajax` and below is the result

[image: Resulted image]

**Update 3**

After changing the `JS`

```
$('#myid').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');

// alert(keys);

 $.ajax({     
  url: '<?= URL::toRoute(["ogpheader/viewsetpdf"])?>',
  dataType: 'json',
  data:{keylist: keys},
   type: 'post',
  success:function(data) {
    alert('Done')
  }
```

});

The result is

[image: Console Image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you debug it in network?try with $.ajax

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh kindly see the update

Comment: your $.post should be changed to $.ajax

Comment: can you change `url: '<?= URL::toRoute(["ogpheader/viewsetpdf"])?>',` to `url: '<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(["/ogpheader/viewsetpdf"])?>',` and in the action `viewtestpdf ` add `echo "hello"; exit;` in the first line , and check the console , your console image that you have added contains the whole php statement in the params which should not be, also you should use `$this->registerJs()` with `yii\web\View::POS_END` .

Comment: I have changed the code as per your suggestion, and added `$this->registerJs()` now I have got an exception `ArgumentCountError` the detail is `oo few arguments to function yii\web\View::registerJs(), 0 passed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the controller and see what return, probably csrf token missing that why you got empty output

```
public function actionViewsetpdf()
{
    if(isset($_POST['keylist']))
    {
        $keys = json_decode($_POST['keylist']);
        print_r($keys);
    }
    else{
        echo 'no data';
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It displays `no data`

Answer (score 2):

POST method required csrf token so you have to pass _csrf token as a parameter

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ogpheader/viewsetpdf',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        keylist: keys,
        _csrf: '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Or you can disable csrf valdation by adding this to your controller

```
public function beforeAction()
    {      
        if ($this->action->id == 'viewsetpdf') {
            Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Or simplest way just change POST to GET

Comment: I doubt that, have you tried them all, what error return?

Comment: Where to add this `beforeAction` method ?

Comment: When adding `_csrf: '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'` and refreshing the page it gives me error `Undefined variable: app`

Comment: Make sure there is "use Yii;" after namespace "ogpheader\controllers;"
if not, add it

Comment: `use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use app\models\User;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use Yii;`

These are my namespace

Comment: By using `use Yii;` I am unable to get the controller through which I am getting all the details

Answer (score 1):

`$.post()` has limited parameter to pass. Use `$.ajax()`. Also you need to add `e.preventDefault()` to stop redirection from `a` tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {      

 $('#myid').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');

    // alert(keys);

     $.ajax({     
      url: '<?php echo URL::toRoute(["ogpheader/viewsetpdf"]); ?>',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:{keylist: keys},
       type: 'post',
      success:function(data) {
        alert('Done')
      }

 });
}) });
```

Comment: Kindly see the update 2 I have placed my full view with the `url`

Comment: Try to change `e.preventdefault()` to `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: changed the `e.preventdefault();` to `e.preventDefault();` now in network I am getting `404`

Comment: No... change only in ajax

Comment: Tried but again same `Not Found (#404): Page not found.`

Comment: Show your console

Comment: I have added the images of console. Kindly see it

Comment: will you try `php echo` instead of short tag. check updated answer

Comment: Still the same response :(

Comment: Yes it's inside the php tag

Comment: I am asking about `php file` not `tag`. what is extension of your js code file?

Comment: Yes it's inside the `php` file. The starting of `JS` is `$script = <<< JS` and the ending is `JS;
$this->registerJs($script);`

Answer (score 0):

Use below js

```
<?php
$url = Url::toRoute(['ogpheader/viewsetpdf']);
$this->registerJs(<<< JS
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#myid').click(function() {
      var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
      $.ajax({
         url: '$url',
         data: {keylist: keys},
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         success:function(data) {
            alert('Done');
         }
      });
   });
});
JS
); ?>
```

Comment: Tried your code. But again I am getting the blank page